# HTTP Response for Failed XML Schema Validation

Tags: xml, scala, validation, playframework

I am building an XML validation function in Scala, using Scala Play 2.5.x. I want to return an error if the XML passed in does not match the expected schema. I've stripped my function down into pseudocode below:

```
def myfunc(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async(parse.xml) { implicit request =>
  if(/*request matches schema*/) //do something and return 200
  else //throw exception
}
```

My problem is this:

- The above function returns a `200` if the request matches the schema I have provided elsewhere in the code.
- If it doesn't match the schema, what type of HTTP response would it be best practice to return? Will a `400` suffice? Would  something like `500` be better? Is there a best practice for HTTP response codes upon failed validation?

Whatever error I throw is being handled with a `.recover {...}` in the function calling `myfunc` and the end user just sees a "Service Unavailable" page, so this is really just for debugging purposes as my application is pretty large and consists of multiple microservices.

Comment: IMHO I think you're right with a `400` but I think this question is a bit broad and mostly opinion based.

Comment: @MattJones I was wondering if there is any proper "best practice" or industry standard way to deal with validation failures like this, or if it is just personal preference.